# CSS - How I can cut the height footer

Tags: html, css

I'm having a issue with a footer in my page.

I have 2 divs - One with a black background, and other with a White background and a image (with transparent background) where the image is over 50% the black background and 50% over the White background.

To make this effect I create a style:

```
.divimage {
position: relative;
top: -110px
}
```

Then, The image goes -110px over the black background.

ok?

But, with this I have a 110px height of White background under the image now.

There is a way to cut this "extra" 110px out?

I tried many options, nothing happens.

(tried: min-height, max-height, height..)

I create a JSFIDDLE to explain better.. 
https://jsfiddle.net/do1tn64h/

Its a simple html - and If you delete the style="position: relative; top: -110px" of container, the image will down and the footer will be perfect, ending at 2, 3 pixels of distance of the image.

but, with this style, the image goes up 110px over the black background, and now I have 110px of White space under...

Comment: add html code too. Also fiddle would be useful

Comment: @murli2308 hi! I'm writting the jsdfiddle.. :D - updated the question with the link  tks!!

Comment: hi @CoderDudeTwodee the image is the graybox on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`margin-top:-110px;` instead of `top:-110px;`

Also use `z-index` if you want to make it up.

udpated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/do1tn64h/1/

Comment: tks!! I past the last two hours testing many solutions.. and nothing!! You are my hero!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Save my day! tks!!! :D